# TOPN DAX function Showing blank value in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, greatest-n-per-group, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-filters

There seems to be a problem with my DAX code:

```
Top Selling Prod by Quantity = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(Transactions[ITEM_ID])
,TOPN([Selected N], Transactions, [Total Quantity], DESC))
```

The Selected N code:

```
Selected N = SELECTEDVALUE('Select Top N'[Select N])
```

The code (Measure for Total Quantity):

```
Total Quantity = sum(Transactions[QTY_INVOICED])
```

It shows a blank value until something is selected (like a sale or a product or something like that on another visual). The thing is that I want it to show the Top 1, or Top 2 or Top 3 depending on what number is selected in the Select N Slicer. So in short, the slicer for the TOPN doesn't work and the card shows a blank value until something else is select, like a sale or product name.

Transactions Table

```
| ITEM_ID   | Total Quantity   
|:--------  |:---------------|
| CH15      | 25283          |   
| CH16      | 25006          |
| CH17      | 18505          |
| CH18      | 18440          |  
| CH37      | 17599          |
```

I want the card visual to show the top selling item (Item_ID) by Total Quantity based on the selected value on the slicer:

The Expected Result Result is :

```
-------
|CH15 |
-------
```

Displayed on a card visual

Comment: You need to reformat your posted tables and clarify the expected results for the posted data.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I got the formatting right. I am still learning stack overflow. Really sorry..

Answer (score 1):

You'd need something like:

```
=TOPN (
    1,
    TOPN (
        [Selected N],
        VALUES ( Transactions[ITEM_ID] ),
        [Total Quantity], DESC
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you soo much @Jos Wooley, it does work only when you remove [Selected N] and place a 1. But if [Selected N] is bigger than 5, then you do get the top 5 products, just not in the correct order, so I think I will have to rank it. But thanks mate